# Creating multiple instances of MMDrawerController

Tags: swift, swift2, mmdrawercontroller

I am wondering if this is possible?

I am able to get one instance working, but would like to have another instance with a different cells.

I have tried creating a new instance of `MMDrawercontroller` in my `AppDelegate` but when I call it nothing is happening.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I have not used it, but the demo on https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mmdrawercontroller--2 has two - one on the left, and one on the right.

Comment: In that example, the left and right menus are one instance of `mmdrawecontroller`